# how to prevent jump to top of page

Tags: javascript, jquery

not sure why i'm having this problem. This is only happening on mobile IOS devices. Every time i click , it jumps to top of page

```
var thisImageClick = '<i class="fa fa-times-circle" data-placement="left" title="Remove Player" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="removeStarter(\''+positionID+'\'); return false;"></i>';
```

I tried adding 
    return false;

but that wouldn't work , any ideas ?

Here is removeStarter function

```
            function removeStarter(positionID){
                previousLineupTab = currentLineupTab;
                switch(positionID) {
                    case "QB": currentLineupTab=0; break;
                    case "RB1":
                    case "RB2": currentLineupTab=1; break;
                    case "WR1":
                    case "WR2":
                    case "WR3": currentLineupTab=2; break;
                    case "TE": currentLineupTab=3; break;
                    case "FLEX": currentLineupTab=4; flexPlayer=""; break;
                    case "D": currentLineupTab=5; break;
                }
                var pid = starterArray[positionID];
                starterArray[positionID]='';
                sourceList["pid_"+pid].Selected = false;
                populateStarters(false);
                showLineupTab(currentLineupTab,false,false);
            }
```

Comment: can you share code of removeStarter method .?

Comment: sry should have posted the function , though i'm not setting any window position in it

Comment: `removeStarter` is useless

Comment: Also what should be `onclick="removeStarter(\''+positionID+'\')"` ? If that's HTML, why do you use `+`  and escapes?

Comment: Is this inside of an anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider not use onclick directly on your element, you may use jquery function to execute this action as a event listener.

But considering that you will not change your actual solution, you may to the following:

```
<i class="fa fa-times-circle" data-placement="left" title="Remove Player" style="cursor:pointer" onclick="removeStarter(\''+positionID+'\'); return false;"></i>
```

Ref: http://biostall.com/page-jumping-to-top-when-clicking-link-containing-click-event/

Comment: i've tried both , but it still jumps to top of page , this is only happening on mobile IOS , desktop browsers are fine  , i do have scroll(0,0); set on the page on refresh , but this is just a onclick event

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you're inside an anchor (`<a></a>`). If it is, do `<a href='#0'></a>`.